# Android SQLiteDatabaseLockedException with ormlite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48 on Android.

I utilize OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper with singleton pattern (only one instance for the entire app).

I wrote a testing app (using multiple AsyncTask with read/create/update 
operations) and it works fine, even test it in Release mode.

It works fine on actual production/release running on my phone (Samsung S3 and Mi4i), but occasionally I receive bug report with SQLiteDatabaseLockedException from other users.

I wonder did I do something wrong, or SQLite have different unpredictable behavior on different android phone?

Below are some of my code:

```
public class DbHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<ModelA, String> modelADao = null;

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    // this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, ModelA.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public Dao<ModelA, String> getModelADao() throws SQLException {
    if (modelADao == null) {
        modelADao = getDao(ModelA.class);
    }
    return modelADao;
    }
}

@DatabaseTable(tableName = "model_a")
public class ModelA {
    @DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "_id")
    public String id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "created")
    public Date created;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "name")
    public String name;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "age")
    public int age;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "is_active")
    public boolean isActive;
}

public class App {
    public static final String TAG = App.class.getName();

    private static DbHelper dbHelper;

    public synchronized static DbHelper buildDbHelper(Context context) {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "buildDbHelper");
        dbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DbHelper.class);
    }
    return dbHelper;
    }

    public static DbHelper getDbHelper() {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getDbHelper=null");
    }
    return dbHelper;
    }
}

# Read
List<ModelA> items = App.getDbHelper().getModelADao().queryForAll();

# Create
Dao<ModelA, String> dao = App.getDbHelper().getModelADao();
ModelA item = new ModelA();
item.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
item.name = item.id;
item.created = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
item.age = rand.nextInt(100);
dao.create(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of exception generally comes when you are creating more than once instance of database class and more than one instance tries to access database at the same time.Try using Singleton approach it will definitely solve your problem.
Let me know if you need any assistance in it.
happy coding :)
Mark this up if it helps.

Comment: I did use a SIngleton approach as shown in my code above :(